# getting the total sum and group them by total sale top 3 for across 3 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to have a 3 months of report (month 7-9) that shows the top 3 product for each month based on the sum of their "overtarget"(or sale). Here is my data (this one just shows week #27)

```
select * from MV_CUSTOMER_ORDERSR27 s
where s.BRANCH_ID = 1
and s.WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL = 27;

  YEAR     MONTH_NUMBER_OVERALL WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL  REGION_ID PRODUCT_ID  BRANCH_ID OVERTARGET
---------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      2014                    7                  27          1          1          1         30 
      2014                    7                  27          1          2          1         11 
      2014                    7                  27          1          3          1         14 
      2014                    7                  27          1          4          1          1 
      2014                    7                  27          1          5          1          7 
      2014                    7                  27          1          1          1        -20 
      2014                    7                  27          1          2          1         19 
      2014                    7                  27          1          3          1        -26 
      2014                    7                  27          1          4          1          5 
      2014                    7                  27          1          5          1         12 
      2014                    7                  27          1          1          1        -30 
      2014                    7                  27          1          2          1        -21 
      2014                    7                  27          1          3          1          3 
      2014                    7                  27          1          4          1         20 
      2014                    7                  27          1          5          1        -14 
      2014                    7                  27          1          1          1         19 
      2014                    7                  27          1          2          1        -17 
      2014                    7                  27          1          3          1          2 
      2014                    7                  27          1          4          1        -16 
      2014                    7                  27          1          5          1         22 
      2014                    7                  27          1          1          1        -29 
      2014                    7                  27          1          2          1          2 
      2014                    7                  27          1          3          1          3 
      2014                    7                  27          1          4          1        -29 
      2014                    7                  27          1          5          1         27
```

and I've been trying to come up something like this

```
  YEAR     MONTH_NUMBER_OVERALL WEEK_NUMBER_OVERALL  REGION_ID PRODUCT_ID OVERTARGET
---------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
  2014                    7                   1          1          5             21
  2014                    7                   1          1          3             18
  2014                    7                   1          1          2              9
  2014                    8                   1          1          1             20
  2014                    8                   1          1          2             11
  2014                    8                   1          1          4              6
  2014                    9                   1          1          3             18
  2014                    9                   1          1          2             13
  2014                    9                   1          1          5              5
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that helps:

```
SELECT year,
       month_number_overall,
       product_id,
       overtarget
  FROM(SELECT year,
              month_number_overall,
              product_id,
              overtarget,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year, month_number_overall 
                                     ORDER BY overtarget DESC) AS rank
         FROM(SELECT year,
                     month_number_overall,
                     product_id,
                     SUM(overtarget) AS overtarget
                FROM yourtable
               WHERE year = 2014
                 AND month_number_overall BETWEEN 7 AND 9
               GROUP
                  BY year,
                     month_number_overall,
                     product_id
             )
      )
 WHERE rank < 4
 ORDER
    BY 1, 2, 4 DESC
```

Comment: You forgot GROUP BY in the most inner query